# Why does this.value return undefined but works fine if put inside a function?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, this

I'm learning javascript, I'm new to programming and i was wondering about "this".

```
let someObject = {
    a : "happy",
    b : "sad",
    c : function(){
        return this.a
    },
    d : this.a
}
```

`someObject.c()` returns "happy" but `someObject.d` returns undefined. why can't it simply assign the value of 'a' to 'd'?

Comment: Js is function scoped meaning that when you set d here: `d : this.a` - "this" doesn't refer to `someObject`, it refers to the nearest function scope (or just the global one if not inside any functions). [More info on how 'this' works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: It is not so simple how the keyword "this" is bound in JS. Several rules are applied, described here https://codeburst.io/the-simple-rules-to-this-in-javascript-35d97f31bde3.

Comment: In short, for current situation, your this is used in global context, so refers to the 'window' object. As window does not have property 'd', it returns undefined. If you put 'this' inside function and put this function in object literal, 'this' starts to refer this object. There are a lot caveats with this in JS, so I advise to read manuals carefully.